# Search page on the django

Tags: python, django, search

I want to an easy way to create search page on my site to searching only the titles.
What is the easiest way for to do that?

I am the new to django and I dont know how to do this better,
I've read manuals but is confusing.

This is my code so far:

```
import re
from django.db.models import Q
def normalize_query(query_string,
                    findterms=re.compile(r'"([^"]+)"|(\S+)').findall,
                    normspace=re.compile(r'\s{2,}').sub):
    ''' Splits the query string in invidual keywords, getting rid of unecessary spaces
        and grouping quoted words together.
        Example:

        >>> normalize_query('  some random  words "with   quotes  " and   spaces')
        ['some', 'random', 'words', 'with quotes', 'and', 'spaces']

    '''
    return [normspace(' ', (t[0] or t[1]).strip()) for t in findterms(query_string)] 

def get_query(query_string, search_fields):
    ''' Returns a query, that is a combination of Q objects. That combination
        aims to search keywords within a model by testing the given search fields.

    '''
    query = None # Query to search for every search term        
    terms = normalize_query(query_string)
    for term in terms:
        or_query = None # Query to search for a given term in each field
        for field_name in search_fields:
            q = Q(**{"%s__icontains" % field_name: term})
            if or_query is None:
                or_query = q
            else:
                or_query = or_query | q
        if query is None:
            query = or_query
        else:
            query = query & or_query
    return query
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    query_string = ''
    found_entries = None
    if ('q' in request.GET) and request.GET['q'].strip():
        query_string = request.GET['q']

        entry_query = get_query(query_string, ['title', 'body',])

        found_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entry_query).order_by('-pub_date')

    return render_to_response('search/search_results.html',
                          { 'query_string': query_string, 'found_entries': found_entries },
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

First in the pycharm show me red line under this 'RequestContext'
and if I run this I get an error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:
GET 
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=post+one
```

Comment: What search do you want to support? Is string search enough?

Comment: Your way of combining `Q` objects is already doing that. What else you don't understand?

Comment: It looks like your URL patterns aren't set up right, and the best tool for search * is [Django-Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) --- * asked before my edit, and removed because its off-topic, but the rest isn't

Comment: you are getting a 404 which means the `/search/` was not resolved. Look at your root url conf